# How to determine messageType interface for MDB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, message-driven-bean

A MessageDriveBean implement another interface in addition to MessageListener.
This provide an exception at deployement:

> Caused by: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating
>   ejb container MyQueue: Unable to choose messagingType interface
>   for MDB MyQueue from [interface
>   IMessageVisitor, interface
>   javax.jms.MessageListener]

Any idea to specify the messageType interface ?

Comment: please provide code snippet that shows how your MDB is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I should explicitely mention the messaging type (found from [jboss forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/164246))

```
@MessageDriven(messageListenerInterface=MessageListener.class)
```